# Touch-action pra que serve? CSS

Tags: css, css3, google-chrome

Estou recebendo um aviso no console do *Google Chrome*:

> [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080
>   e @ 332526c6e8d3fc1326ad773f97b0a486.js:5029
>   dispatch @ 332526c6e8d3fc1326ad773f97b0a486.js:583
>   r.handle @ 332526c6e8d3fc1326ad773f97b0a486.js:583

Usando o `touch-action: none;` no `body` de meu *site*, esse aviso não aparece mais.

1. Gostaria de saber o por quê do aviso? e
2. o que a `touch-action: none;` faz pra remover o mesmo?

Comment: Sobre o `touch-action:none` vc pode ler mais aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action pelo que eu entendi ele desabilita todas as funções Touch da tela (pan e zoom).

Comment: Sobre o "bug" aqui tem mais uma referencia, veja do item 2.5 até 2.7 https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#defining-event-interfaces outra coisa, algumas versões do FireFox vc tem que habilitar o Flag `layout.css.touch_action.enabled` referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Experimental_features

Answer (score 2):

A propriedade `touch-action` permite você decidir qual será o comportamento de toque daquele item em dispositivos sensiveis, por exemplo:

```
/* Keyword values */
touch-action: auto;
touch-action: none;
touch-action: pan-x;
touch-action: pan-left;
touch-action: pan-right;
touch-action: pan-y;
touch-action: pan-up;
touch-action: pan-down;
touch-action: pinch-zoom;
touch-action: manipulation;

/* Global values */
touch-action: inherit;
touch-action: initial;
touch-action: unset;
```

Esses são os possíveis valores que o `touch-action` pode ter.

Como resposta parcial a sua pergunta `touch-action:none` desabilita todos os gestos de "pinça" e zoom que o usuário executar.

Fonte sobre o `touch-action`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action